# Adding date column to pandas dataframe with 200000 rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I run following code to add date column to dataframe `df1` of shape `(200000, 115)`starting from today:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(index=range(200000),columns=range(115)) # create dummy data frame
start_date = datetime.date.today()
end_date = start_date + datetime.timedelta(days=200000)
df1['date'] = pd.date_range(start=start_date, end=end_date)
```

But this gives me following error:

```
OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 2570-10-24 00:00:00c
```

How do add date column without getting an error?

Comment: Why do you want to add 200_000 days from today? What is the expected result?

Comment: pandas allows dates to be only in a certain range. you can check the min and max using this: print(pd.Timestamp.min), print(pd.Timestamp.max)

Do you need the frequency of the dates to be daily?

Comment: @Corralien I just want them any 200000 dates, given that they are in sequence. Should I try some past date instead of today? Or its simply not possible to have columns with 200000 dates?

Comment: 200k days is around 550years... Is that really intentional?

Comment: @Corralien that's only on 32-bit systems. On my system, `pd.Timestamp.max` is `Timestamp('2262-04-11 23:47:16.854775807')`. Still not 550 years, but much farther away than 2038. `min` was in 1677.

Comment: @MattDMo. Yes you are right, old memory :-)

Comment: On my machine, its `1677-09-21 00:12:43.145224193` to `2262-04-11 23:47:16.854775807`. Thats 580 years. But still `start_date = datetime.datetime.strptime('1677-09-21','%Y-%m-%d')` gives error `OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 2570-10-24 00:00:00`. It should work right?

Comment: @MsA that's ~585 years, so just put your 200,000 days between them.

Comment: @MsA try using `1677-09-22` as your start date. If you omit the time, the datetime object defaults to midnight.

Comment: Ohkay done finally. But now I believe that was not required! I was trying [get_forecasting_splits](https://timeseriesai.github.io/tsai/data.validation.html#get_forecasting_splits), which takes `datetime_col` as argument. But realized its optional!